# Do hostgator support zend framework?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, hosting, shared-hosting

Does hostgator support Zend framework in shared hosting? if not then what are other good hosting providers that support zend framework on shared hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to correct my self. Zend framework is supported by hostgator, but not for all plans. Zend Framework is not installed in Shared or Reseller servers. You may need to upgrade to either a VPS or dedicated server to get Framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [FatCow](http://www.fatcow.com/) and [BlueHost](http://www.bluehost.com/).